# A scatola chiusa

Tags: idioms, phrase-origin

[A scatola chiusa](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/scatola/) è un modo di dire  molto comune che viene usato soprattutto in espressioni come:

> - ***comprare a scatola  chiusa,*** senza accertarsi della qualità della merce, per fiducia nella bontà del prodotto, o per ingenuità e simili.

*Treccani.it* riguardo ad un espressione analoga dice:

> - ***vendere a scatola chiusa,*** *in origine con riferimento soprattutto all’acquisto di opere cinematografiche*.

Secondo [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20scatola%20chiusa&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20scatola%20chiusa%3B%2Cc0) l'espressione *'a scatola chiusa'* si e diffusa a partire agli anni '40.

L'origine di tale modo di dire sembrerebbe essere, secondo Treccani, legato al mondo del cinema. Qualcuno ha altre informazioni a riguardo? In che senso le opere cinematografiche venivano vendute *a scatola chiusa*? È questa la sua vera origine?

Comment: Qualcuno avrà visto di sfuggita una mia risposta, nella quale mi pareva di avere trovato (con NGram) un utilizzo del 1831. Purtroppo però si tratta di un commento del 1987 (circa) ad una riproduzione in facsimile di un'opera di Leopardi stampata nel 1831. Questo anche per dire che con NGram bisogna stare attenti (secondo Google Books il libro era datato 1831).

Comment: Non ho approfondito, ma qualcosa di potenzialmente interessante sull'uso di “a scatola chiusa” in ambito cinematografico si può forse trovare [qui](https://books.google.it/books?id=TAE-ffbFs0oC&pg=PA86&dq=%22a+scatola+chiusa%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22a%20scatola%20chiusa%22&f=false), all'interno delle memorie di Blasetti, *Il cinema che ho vissuto*.

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer to your question, please consider the option to "accept" it by clicking a checkmark next to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Non credo che Treccani imputi l'origine del termine al mondo cinematografico. Semplicemente ne sottolinea il largo utilizzo in tale settore.

Difatti, sebbene ciò sia veritiero, la prima verificata comparsa del termine è datata 1902, in un'opera scritta da Myrtle Reed intitolata *Lavender and Old Lace*. Ovviamente si parla del corrispettivo statunitense `sight unseen`. La Reed scrive:

> Nevertheless, when she wrote, asking me to take charge of her house while she went to Europe, I gladly consented, **sight unseen**.

La citazione proviene dalla scansione digitale del libro del 1902, attuata dal [Progetto Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/1266/1266-h/1266-h.htm#link2H_4_0005), al quale peraltro ho collaborato per alcune opere italiane e in esperanto.

Alcuni dizionari, tra cui lo statunitense [Farlex](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/sight+unseen), addirittura predatano il primo uso del termine alla fine del 1800, talvolta indicando la data del 1892, ma per quanto ho avuto modo di constatare non citano fonti.

Per quanto riguarda la comparsa del termine nei documenti italiani, invece, non sono riuscito a trovare fonti utili in merito.

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE, @Wiccio!

Comment: Probabilmente il primo uso noto dell'espressione è del 1892 come cita l'OED:   *The Oxford English Dictionary says ***“sight unseen”*** is an American expression for “without inspection” and dates from the 1890s. The OED’s earliest citation, from 1892, is in Dialect Notes, a journal of the American Dialect Society: “To trade knives sight unseen is to swap without seeing each other’s knife.” *http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2007/05/out-of-sight.html

Comment: Quindi l'espressione *a scatola chiusa* sarebbe un traduzione 'creativa' dell'espressione 'sight unseen'?

Comment: Non capisco bene che senso abbia, per commentare o analizzare l'espressione italiana “a scatola chiusa”, commentarne e analizzarne una inglese di significato simile.

Comment: @DaG - Più che un commento, la mia era una domanda. Mi sembra che Wiccio voglia dire che l'espressione italiana derivi  in qualche modo da quella americana.

Comment: Sì, @Josh61, grazie. Ma io mi riferivo proprio alla risposta stessa, che trovo curiosa, non al tuo commento.

Comment: Non vedo alcuna connessione tra “sight unseen” e “a scatola chiusa”.

Comment: @Josh61 Sí. Per quel che ho potuto constatare, l'italiano _a scatola chiusa_ appare dapprima come traduzione del lemma _sight unseen_ utilizzato in testi anglofoni. Proprio per ciò, non saprei analizzare piú in dettaglio la forma italiana, se non in tal modo.
Mi sembrava utile, o quanto meno 'curioso' come è stato definito, citare la storicità dell'utilizzo del lemma madre dal quale deriva la parola italiana.

Comment: @Wiccio: Se è vero che *a scatola chiusa* è una “traduzione” di *sight unseen*, è una scoperta davvero interessante. Come lo sai?

Comment: @Wiccio - Riesci a postare la traduzione fatta nel 1902 ?